# How do I remove new line characters from a string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, string

I need to strip away any new line characters from a string. I tried the stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString method below. What is the correct method to do this in Objective C?

```
[textLine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

Comment: This method generates a new string. Are you saving it, even if in place of the previous one?

Comment: I can generate a new string. It doesn't really matter, just need to strip out any new line chars.

Comment: So, you need to assign that newly generated one (stripped) to the original. EDIT: @sheeptest just posted an answer with the example code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` does not modify `textLine`

```
NSString *strippedTextLine = [textLine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

Or

```
NSString *textLine = @"My cool text\n";
textLine = [textLine stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
```

Comment: That did the trick as I needed to replace new line chars mid string too.

Answer (score 5):

```
NSString *textWithNewLinesRemoved = [textLine stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Does this only trim from the beginning or ending of the string? I need to strip newline chars from middle of string too.

Comment: it trims from both ends of the string